# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always' available

Tags: java, spring

getting error when use Spring Tool suite to run spring batch applications:

```
2018-04-09 13:02:50.638[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19056[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.b.d.svc.rates.mfr.batch.Application   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Application in 3.108 seconds (JVM running for 4.082)
```

[2m2018-04-09 13:02:50.642[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m19056[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.b.d.b.service.AbstractBatchService    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exception in runJob() :

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.bns.dmts.batch.service.AbstractBatchService.runJob(AbstractBatchService.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bns.dmts.svc.rates.mfr.batch.service.RatesMFRBatchService.runJob(RatesMFRBatchService.java:24) [classes/:na]
    at com.bns.dmts.svc.rates.mfr.batch.Application.main(Application.java:28) [classes/:na]

[2m2018-04-09 13:02:50.643[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19056[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.b.d.svc.rates.mfr.batch.Application   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run ends with exit code = -1
[2m2018-04-09 13:02:50.644[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19056[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[       Thread-2][0;39m [36ms.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d68ef40: startup date [Mon Apr 09 13:02:48 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2018-04-09 13:02:50.646[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19056[0;39m [2m--

Comment: Your post is too well formatted...

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked below configuration should resolve below error
[STS Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0vS2.jpg)